# How can I connect an Xperia X8 to an external monitor?

Tags: sony-ericsson-xperia-x8, external-display

Is it possible to connect the Xperia X8 to external monitor? In other words, display the screen from the phone on the monitor?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to find a VNC-like server for the phone.  Using that they should be able to bring up the UI of the phone onto a computer.